# how to initialize dynamic 3d Array help need java

Tags: java, android

hi how i dynamically initialize 3d array
i have 4 table but in each table no of rows are different and columns are 4
each table has different records .how to initialize in loop dynamically
lets suppose 1st table has 4 records
2nd table has 5 records
3rd table has 3 records
4th table has 7 records

e.g String data[][][]= new String[4][unknown][4];

Comment: Your best bet would be to let go of the predisposition that the structure should be an array.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays (even in Java) are statically allocated. The `unknown` size should be calculated to be the maximum value you require.

Essentially what you'll be creating is an array of arrays of strings.

```
String data[][][] = new String[4][7][4]
```

If you want each row to be a different size, you'll be needing to create an array of [LinkedLists](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) or similar data structure.

```
LinkedList<String[]>[4] data = new LinkedList<String []>[4]();
```

Hope that helps.